# SonarQube up-gradation 3.5.1 to 5.0 fails on migration of MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

My Current system Setup is as below:

- SonarQube Version: 3.5.1
- MySQL version: 5.6.11
- Operating System: Windows 2008 R2

I am trying to upgrade SonarQube from 3.5.1 to 5.0 version as per SonarQube [upgrade guide](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading).

When I click on "Upgrade" from UI it throws an error in sonar.log file which I pasted below. An error shows table "snapshot_data" already exist. I have verified and table exist in a database.

Do I know why sonar is checking table which is already exist?

```
2015.02.16 16:53:58 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  CreateSnapshotData: migrating =============================================
2015.02.16 16:53:58 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- create_table(:snapshot_data, {})
2015.02.16 16:53:58 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Table 'snapshot_data' already exists: CREATE TABLE `snapshot_data` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `snapshot_id` integer, `resource_id` integer, `snapshot_data` longtext, `data_type` varchar(50), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:109:in `create_table'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/mysql/adapter.rb:252:in `create_table'
                org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2231:in `send'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `method_missing'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
                jar:file:/D:/sonarqube-5.0/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:348:in `method_missing'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:176:in `create_table'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/config/../lib/../db/migrate/387_create_snapshot_data.rb:28:in `up'
                org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
                jar:file:/D:/sonarqube-5.0/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
                org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
                D:1:in `migrate'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:491:in `migrate'
                org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
                org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:576:in `ddl_transaction'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:490:in `migrate'
                org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in `migrate'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/config/../lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
                D:/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:109:in `start_migration'
                org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
                org/jruby/RubyProc.java:228:in `call'
```

Comment: You will never get an answer with such a question: it's not well formatted, you don't explain your context, you just throw a stacktrace... You are new to Stackoverflow so please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Comment: My Current system Setup is as below:
SonarQube Version: 3.5.1
MySQL version: 5.6.11
Operating System:  Windows 2008 R2

I am trying to upgrade SonarQube from 3.5.1 to 5.0 version as per sonar upgrade guide. (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)

When I click on "Upgrade" from UI it throws an error in sonar.log file which I have already given in the first post.

An error shows table "snapshot_data" already exist.

I have verified and table exist in a database.

Do I know why sonar is checking table which is already exist?

Can you please help?

Comment: Nagendra: you can edit a question to make it clearer. For instance, that's what I did: I added your comment on your question and reformatted it. Is clearer, isn't it? I will answer your question below.

Comment: snapshot_data table already exist in database SonarQube 3.5.1 version.  
- While performing upgrade from SonarQube 3.5.1 to 5.0.     
-I do not know why migration is trying to create snapshot_data table which is already exists in database ?    

**Solution:**

-I deleted 387_create_snapshot_data.rb file and again tried for upgrade.
-This time same error for issues table (398_create_issues.rb)  and issues_changes table (399_create_issue_changes.rb)    

-Again I had deleted 398_create_issues and 399_create_issue_changes file from migration directory and rerun the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot_data table is created during [the migration script #387](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/db/migrate/387_create_snapshot_data.rb), which belongs to SonarQube 3.6.

If you get this error, this probably means that you have previously done a migration that failed and you tried to replay it once again. So what I'd suggest is that you restore the DB in your previous state of SonarQube 3.5.1 (provided that you have a backup for it), and you replay the full migration.